# Jenkins plugin design with radioblock

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

All,

I have been trying to figure this UI piece of my jenkins plugin for a few hours now. I am trying to nest checkboxes inside a radioBlock. The problem I am having is that the checkboxes are not hidden when the page loads at first. To hide them I have to highlight the radio then deselect.

```html
<f:section title="Deployment method"> 
                                   <f:radioBlock checked="true" name="deployMethod" title="Deploy new servers" value="Deploy new Servers"/>
                                  <f:radioBlock checked="false" name="deployMethod" title="Script Deploy" value="Script deploy">
                                      <j:forEach var="script" items="${account.scripts}">
                                           <f:entry>
                                           <f:checkbox name="Scripts" value="${script.scriptName}" title="${script.scriptName}"/> 
                                           </f:entry>
                                      </j:forEach>  
                                  </f:radioBlock>
                                 
                        </f:section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all the content you want to hide inside this:

```
<f:radioBlock checked="false" name="deployMethod" title="Script Deploy" value="Script deploy">
 <f:nested>
 ....
 </f:nested>
</f:radioBlock>
```